# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized (access database)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

what's wrong with my code?I just want to add data into access database but it show `ExecuteNonQuery`:

> Connection property has not been initialized.

It's pretty weird because in other project code similar to this works just fine.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbDataReader reader;

    public Absen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MainForm form_utama;

    private void Absen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Visual Studio Project\Minor baru - back up\Minor baru\Absensi.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (idkaryawantxt.Text != "")
        {
            string q = "insert into tableAbsensi (ID,ID_divisi,Waktu,Tanggal) values ('" + idkaryawantxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + iddivisitxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm :")) + "','" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")) + "')";
            dosomething(q);
        }
    }

    private void dosomething(String q)
    {
        try
            {
                connect.Open();
                command.CommandText = q;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                connect.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set your `Command's` [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
command.Connection = connect;
```

Before execute your command you should set it as the error said

Comment: +1 Plus do not forget to **Dispose** all that objects (connection when  not used and command after execution).

Comment: thanks! you help me~ 

It was pretty funny though XD